# UTF-8 with ResourceBundle

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

in my web-app, UTF-8 characters are shown as question marks while trying to get the string from ResourceBundle object.

In my properties file I have a key value pair as :
CTRY_NAME = Åland Islands

```
    protected Object handleGetObject( String k ){

            ResourceBundle fileBundle;
            cfgBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("CSResBundleCfg", Locale
                                .getDefault());
            bundleName = cfgBundle.getString("BUNDLE_NAME");
            fileBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName, new Locale( language, country, variant),
            Object      result=fileBundle.getString(k);
    }
```

while debugging the code, the key CTRY_NAME has a value �land Islands
 and the same is displayed on UI.

Comment: There are several unknowns in your code. First double check that your properties file is saved with UTF-8 character set. (Simplest way is to open your file with notepad and click "save-as" it offers you to save your file with your current character set so you can find out what it is). Then, the language of your locale may use some charset other then UTF-8. You can use Charset.defaultCharset() to check which is your default one. You can also configure it for your JVM.

Comment: @MichaelGantman.. Thank you.My file encoding was ANSI.